# How can I access a web server running locally when I don't have network access?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to host a website on my MacBook for debugging. But often I don't have any possibilities to connect to a network, so how am I able to access it when I'm not connected to a network?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are not connected to a network, you shold be able to access a website running locally by using `http://localhost/` in the browser of your choice.